# MongoDB aggregate by created_at to return today and yesterday

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on getting dashboard metrics and percentage growth using MongoDB. I have my standard fields in the table with timestamps `createdAt` and `updatedAt`. Using aggregate, I want to group queries like "today" and "yesterday," i.e., today is `{ createdAt = { $gte: startOfToday, $lte: endOfToday }` and yesterday = `{ createdAt = { $gte: startOfYesterday, $lte: endOfYesterday }.` With this, I can calculate the percentage difference between yesterday and today.

For example, I have this in my database:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "created_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T13:53:19.779Z"),
    "updated_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T13:53:19.779Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "created_at": ISODate("2023-04-01T12:53:19.779Z"),
    "updated_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T13:53:19.779Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "created_at": ISODate("2023-04-01T13:54:19.779Z"),
    "updated_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T13:53:19.779Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "created_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T12:53:19.779Z"),
    "updated_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T13:53:19.779Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "created_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T15:24:18.779Z"),
    "updated_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T18:53:19.779Z")
  }
];
```

Lets say today is ISODate("2023-04-02T20:24:18.779Z");

I want to get the following result from the aggregate:

```
"createdAt": [
        {
            "today": 3
        },
        {
            "yesterday": 2
        }
    ]
```

With this, I can calculate the percentage, **(today - yesterday)/yesterday * 100**.

P.S. The result need not be this way, but in a way, I can get today and yesterday in one query.

Comment: @user:3027266 Wernfried Domscheit i need help with this

Comment: here is a starter using facet https://mongoplayground.net/p/QfJrT7yTIrv

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/_PHlwJgEuTd  very very long. if you are usiing node js use new Date please for your own sanity

Comment: @cmgchess Thank you. I used the first one, and it works well. However, I had the issue of empty fields, which would affect the calculation, so I used `$ifNull` in the `$project`, which covered it.

Comment: awesome u can add an answer if u want

Comment: @cmgchess how do i answer the question can't find the answer button

Comment: post your answer below there is a space

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7wNcHNr6a9Y Here is the answer: works for empty slots